# Modify [caption] shortcode so <figure> and <figcaption> are not used?

Tags: shortcode, html5

I would like to use the original (non-html5) version of the [caption] shortcode. That is, I would like to edit the output so that figure and figcaption are not used as they are causing problems.

How can I do this?

Comment: What kind of problems are they causing? Do you have another question where you detail what they are in search of a solution? What lead you to asking how to implement this solution rather than asking about the original problem?

Comment: Figure and figcaption are not compatible with the Apple News plugin my site uses so it's causing errors. I would like to replace these with simple divs but have not found any documentation for how to do it.

Comment: Is that not a bug/support request for the Apple News plugin you use? Would it not be better to keep the tags but replace them specifically in that plugin rather than site wide? Keep in mind that any editor will still use these tags even if you snip them out behind the scenes

Comment: I'm open to any solution but I don't know enough about the plugin to make edits and I've never had any luck posting to plugin pages. I would like to just find a simple workaround if possible.

Comment: You would need to contact the support for the plugin you're using. I couldn't advise as to where ot do that though as I have no idea which plugin you're using

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. There's a filter for img_caption_shortcode that lets you modify what [caption] does. Thank you for your replies.

Comment: Can you post that as an answer?